# How to print a table of numbers in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get Python to print a table with the exact format I've typed on the .txt file, which looks something like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 11 12 13
```

This is my code so far:

```
f = input('Enter the file name: ')
infile = open(f, 'r')
contents = infile.readlines()
infile.close()
table = []

for line in range (len(contents)):
    rows = contents[line].strip().split(' ')
    table.append(rows)
print(table)
```

This is what I get so far after running it, I'm not sure how to continue from here.

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7', '8'], ['9', '11', '12', '13']]
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use numpy array

Comment: @SanketDeshmukh: Why? For someone who is just learning the basics of Python, what is the benefit to adding the complexity of installing and using a third party library?

Comment: If you're trying to print the exact contents of the file, why not just print the exact contents of the file, like with `contents = infile.read(); print(contents)`?

Comment: Your title is completely unrelated to your actual question. You're obviously able to read the file and parse the data. You just want to format it in a tabular way when displaying the data. Please ask concise questions  (title inclused).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Noted. Sorry, am still new to Python and this site. Still, 'preciate the comment and thanks so much for the detailed answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to *up-vote* any answer that you find helpful, and *accept* the one that best answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about formatting. If you explain what you want in English, then you'll see that the code naturally follows.

You want to print each row of data on its own line, with each element separated by a space:

```
def print_table(table):
    for row in table:
        print(' '.join(row))
```

Call this function to display your data.

Another quick solution is to use `pprint`, the pretty-printing library.

```
from pprint import pprint

...
pprint(table)
```

---

The entire thing, optimized to remove unnecessary code and copying:

```
def print_table(table):
    for row in table:
        print(' '.join(row))

def main():
    f = input('Enter the file name: ')

    table = []
    with open(f, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            row = line.strip().split(' ')
            table.append(row)

    print_table(table)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Tips:

- Use `with` to avoid manually closing file and ensuring it is closed even in the even of am exception.
- No need to read the whole file into memory - just use a `for` loop to iterate over each line in the file object itself.
- Use functions!

---

Note that if you want to start using the data as numbers, you'll need to call `int` on each element you read - they're currently all strings. You can easily do this with the `map` function:

```
row = map(int, line.strip().split(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
f = input('Enter the file name: ')
infile = open(f, 'r')
contents = infile.readlines()
infile.close()
table = []

for line in range (len(contents)):
    rows = contents[line].strip().split(' ')
    table.append(rows)

for elem in table:
    print(*elem)
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 11 12 13
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sorry, am new to python but is there a way to make it a nested loop so that I can print it under 'table' instead?

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead of print(table):

```
for line in table:
    wholeline = ""
    for i in line:
         wholeline += str(i)
    print(wholeline)
```